# How do I call a method in application_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method in my application controller:

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
    locale = params[:locale].to_s.strip.to_sym
    I18n.locale = I18n.available_locales.include?(locale) ?
    locale :
        I18n.default_locale
end

def set_locale_or_redirect
    unless no_locale_needed?
       if params[:locale].present?
           @current_locale = I18n.locale = params[:locale]
       else
           redirect_to locale: 'fr'
       end
    end
end
```

What I would like to do is put a link in the `layouts/mylayout.html.erb` (I have my navigation menu there too) pointing to the current url but setting a locale in params and calling `set_locale`.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to point a link to the current page. This quick little hack might work for you

`link_to 'English', url_for('?locale=eng')`

Comment: Unfortunately not. This produces the url `http://localhost:3000/fr/bla/foo/bar?locale=eng` I have the locale "fr" in the url, not after a `? `

Comment: @thiebo can you post the routes for this action? `params` usually are after the `?` or in the post action

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
<%= link_to 'nl', url_for( :locale => 'nl') %>
```